# How to deal this error? TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python

```
drugbank = pd.read_excel('E:/Python工程/数据挖掘实例/test/drugbank/drugbank_extract.xlsx')

print(drugbank)
#从一系列逗号分隔的字符串中返回列表
def chainer(s):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(s.str.split('|')))

#计算分裂的长度
lens = drugbank['synonyms'].str.split('|').map(len)

#创建新的数据框，根据需要重复或链接
res = pd.DataFrame({'drugbankid': np.repeat(drugbank['drugbankid'], lens),
                    'commonname': np.repeat(drugbank['commonname'], lens),
                    'synonyms': chainer(drugbank['synonyms'])})
print(res)
```

When I run the above code, I always get the following error, how should I solve it?

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Comment: What line do you get the error on? What's the full traceback?

Comment: This can't be your real code.  `drugbank` is an undefined variable.  Please show us the real code.

Comment: Sorry, there is a problem in some places in the code I have changed the edit. I am getting an error when I run this line--------->lens = drugbank['synonyms'].str.split('|').map(len)

Answer (score 1):

```py
lens = len(drugbank['synonyms'].str.split('|'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can't solve the problem after trying it, and the same error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

## What usually causes this problem?

Float objects do not have length properties - so the `len()` function won't be able to find a property it does not have. If you want to find the length of the float, convert it to a string first, using the `str()` function. Encase the `str()` function in a `len()` function, and **bam** - you get the length of the float.

```
>>>my_float = 1.3424561
>>>len(str(my_float))
9
```

## The solution and problem in this case

len() is a function, not a parameter. You need to define len as:

```
lens = len(drugbank['synonyms'].str.split('|'))
```

*P.S. It is bad practice to name variables names similar to built in functions and methods, due to possible confusion caused*.

## What else may cause this problem?

In python, `map` returns an `iterator`. Therefore, you need to convert your value into a list using the `list()` function - which you did perfectly in the chainer function, but less perfectly when defining `lens`. You're lens definition should be:

```
lens = list(drugbank['synonyms'].str.split('|').map(len))
```

Also, len should not go inside map - hence

## What else could cause this problem?

However, in your specific case, as you are not dealing with any values that are explicitly defined as a float (at least from our view), I would assume the float is coming from the document (database). In your case, just wrap all definitions in the `str()` function - This way you will be assured to get the one that is the problem.

##### More "correct" solution

Rather than wrapping everything in `str()`, you can do some debugging. With debugging tools and break points, you can tell exactly when this error occurs, and, in turn, only have to wrap that section in `str()`. Your error message may also you the line this is occurring on - no debugging tools needed.

##### Why work with strings?

The nice thing about strings is they can represent other data types, so you can work with multiple data types, and then convert it back once you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can't solve the problem after trying it, and the same error still occurs. This works when I extract the first 100 data, however when adding more data it still gives the same error.

Comment: @SXWgogogo send me the data - I can figure out the problem if i have the database. My discord is alien_jedi#2563, or you can post it on github and i'll have a look at it

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your generosity, is it convenient to give me your email address, I will send the data to your email.